# How to change multiple background-images' position on the same element with jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#d_header-right-lower li." + navEl).css("background-image","url('/header/bg-nav.png'), url('/header/bg-nav-separate.gif')");
$("#d_header-right-lower li." + navEl).css("background-position","0 13px");
$("#d_header-right-lower li." + navEl).css("background-position","bottom center");
$("#d_header-right-lower li." + navEl).css("background-repeat","no-repeat, no-repeat");
```

I don't need `bottom center` for the second `background-image (bg-nav-separate.gif)`; Is there a way to apply it only for the first `background-image (bg-nav.png)`

```
$("#d_header-right-lower li." + navEl).css("background-position (for first image only)","bottom center");
```

Comment: Why not using `.css` with object as parameter

Comment: @Tushar Thank you for your comment. I need to do it on hover element that is not in header area.

Comment: Then use pure CSS `:hover`. No need of jQ here.

Comment: @Tushar the elements I'm hovering on is far from header's elements I want to change background for.

Comment: @whitesiroi `:hover` will work if your header elements and elements for which you want to change background are nested with each-other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting second parameter to `background-position` property to `0 13px` at single call to `.css()` , with parameters separated by comma `,` ; removing second call to `.css("background-position")` . See [Using CSS multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Using_CSS_multiple_backgrounds)

```
.css("background-position","bottom center, 0 13px");
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rgwnye91/1/

Comment: God bless you, it works perfectly. Thank you, thank you, thank you.